# How to setSoftInput for a activity containing navHostFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard, window-soft-input-mode

I want my views in a fragment to be resized when the soft keyboard appears. I tried setting the windowsoftInputMethod in the manifest, in the activity containing the fragments, and even in the fragments separately but nothing is happening. If I remove the NavHostFragment from my layout the methods are working